# Set Request Header keyword in Robot Framework doesn't set header as expected

Tags: http, post, robotframework, keyword-argument

I am setting custom header for POST method using HttpLibrary.HTTP keyword Set Request Header

But when I run the test case, in wireshark I don't see POST method going with the header value I set.

Also library doesn't compute Content-Length.

As per the code header is set in kwargs[] parameter, but the content in the parameter is not sent while doing Http POST.

```
kwargs = {}
        if 'Content-Type' in self._request_headers:
            kwargs['content_type'] = self._request_headers['Content-Type']
self._response = self.app.post(url, self._request_body or {}, self._request_headers, **kwargs
```

post is done to the requestted url but header is not set as expected

Comment: What is your question? You've made an observation but haven't asked anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, and I found that I was using the combination of 'Create New HTTP Context' and 'GET' wrong. It turns out you should only give the part of the url that hasn't already been specified in the 'Create New HTTP Context' keyword

Incorrect:

```
Create New HTTP Context | mywebsite.com
Set Request Header | key | value
Get http://mywebsite.com/specific/uri
```

Correct:

```
Create New HTTP Context | mywebsite.com
Set Request Header | key | value
Get /specific/uri
```